# Schema Registry migration - KSQL error - SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema for id x

Tags: avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, ksqldb

Copied the _schemas topic from one(1) data center to another data center(2) new _schemas_test topic and modified the schema-registry keystore property in 2nd data center to _schemas_test topic.

After this, started facing issues "SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro schema for id x"

As id's are different in 2nd data center compared to 1st data center so this is possibly correct error. Verified that 'x' id in the error is valid in 1st data center old schema. Both data center's run same ksql queries and same topics.
Tried altering the schemas and then reverting to older version, did not fix the error.

Is there a way these errors be fixed so 2nd data center can use schema backup from 1st data center and vice versa?
And how these monotonically increasing id's utilized by producer and consumer to serialize and de-serialize using AVRO format?
Is there a way to reset or refresh id's for all producer and consumer based on latest active version for each topic in schema registry?

Comment: The IDs should not be different if you correctly copied the topics between clusters. Are you sure the "registry-2" is using the _schemas_test topic?

Comment: Also [refer docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/installation/migrate.html) or [my blog post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-tutorial-transfer-avro-schemas-across-schema-registry-clusters/) on migrating schemas